# Maven fat jar not using its own dependency packages

Tags: maven, apache-spark, jar, dependencies

I've created a maven fat jar that works as expected in my local machine. But when I submit the jar in a spark based cluster (HDI/Azure Synapse), it's not using its own dependency packages but rather using spark's dependencies.
In specific, I'm using com.squareup.okio:okio:1.15.0 package and spark dependencies has com.squareup.okio:okio:1.6.0 in [Azure Synapse docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/spark/apache-spark-24-runtime)

Now, this earlier version is missing a class method, and my remote jobs are failing with this error

`User class threw exception: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: okio.ByteString.startsWith(Lokio/ByteString;)Z`

I've tried explicitly referencing this package's jar as well but somehow it defaults to using spark's package version.

Any help on this would be much appreciated.